# Python program crashes when I am calculating a ratio

Tags: python

Following is my code

```
recession_begin='2008q3'
recession_end ='2009q4'
recession_bottom = '2009q2'

university_towns = (returns a dataframe 517 * 2 columns with a multi index of State and Region name)

housing_df = (returns a dataframe 10730* 67 columns with a multi index of state and region name and with data of year quarters)
```

The program dies on the following line: (runs out of memory)

```
housing_df['ratio'] = housing_df[recession_begin]/housing_df[recession_end]
```

What could I be doing wrong? I need to calculate the ratio showing the decline or growth of housing prices between the recession start and the recession bottom.

Comment: are you trying to load a dataset larger than your memory?

Comment: Please also add the error you got when the program crashed

Comment: I restarted the kernel and the problem was resolved. I believed the server was out of memory. Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a broadcasting issue if you have multi-level columns; without an actual snippet of the data, I can't tell for sure, but assuming you have more than 1GB in excess memory, you're probably attempting to divide a dataframe by another dataframe whose column names don't match, which tries to return a huge dataframe of NaNs.

Easiest way to check: try running `housing_df[recession_begin].values/housing_df[recession_end].values`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The line above returns an array of floats.
When I restarted the kernel the problem was resolved.